# Django 2.2 and Rest Framework 3.11 - partial updating model "owner" field (ForeignKey) with owner's username string instead of pk

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Django 2.2 and Rest Framework 3.11

I have an Alarm model. Every alarm instance can optionally have an owner (the standard django User model).

I want to be able to partially update (PATCH) an alarm by setting its owner **just using his/her username (string)** instead of the pk.

Right now, I can update an alarm's owner only by using his/her pk.

I tried various things, like:

- override the update() method in the AlarmSerializer class but whenever I use the owner's username string instead of the pk in the PATCH call, I get back:

```json
{
    "owner": [
        "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str."
    ]
}
```

- play with nested serializers and lookup_field but no luck so far.

The api call (PATCH) should look like this:

```
url: /api/alarms/{alarm_id}/
```

Payload:

```json
{
"owner": "owner_username"
}
```

How can I do that? Thanks

models.py

```py
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

class Alarm(models.Model):
"""
this class is meant to represent a network alarm (a.k.a. event or ticket)
coming from some monitoring system (Zabbix, Nagios, etc.)
"""
customer = models.CharField(max_length=50)
owner = models.ForeignKey(
    settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
    models.SET_NULL,
    blank=True,
    null=True,
)
managed = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=False, verbose_name="Managed ?")
device_type = models.CharField(max_length=150)
...
```

serializers.py

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Alarm

class AlarmSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Alarm
        fields = [
                "customer",
                "owner",
                "device_type",
                "device_name",
                "ip_address",
                "date",
                ]
```

views.py

```py
from rest_framework import viewsets

from .models import Alarm
from .serializers import AlarmSerializer

# Create your views here.

class AlarmViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Alarm.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AlarmSerializer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution: convert the owner username string in pk inside the ModelViewSet.

You need to override the partial_update() method inside the ModelViewSet in views.py.

This view gets hit by the api PATCH call before serialization validation kicks in; hence this is the correct place to swap the username string with the username pk.

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.response import Response

from .models import Alarm
from .serializers import AlarmSerializer


class AlarmViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Alarm.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AlarmSerializer
    
    def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        
        # if the owner field is not a string, it should be
        # a legit pk, so we don't do anything.
        if isinstance(request.data["owner"], str):
            owner_username = request.data.pop("owner")
            owner = get_object_or_404(User, username=owner_username)
            request.data["owner"] = owner.pk

        serializer = self.serializer_class(instance, data=request.data, partial=True)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()

        return Response(serializer.data)
```